# How to copy only the newer files? Python script. Unix Host

Tags: python, unix, copy, unix-timestamp

I've to copy from a Remote Host to Local.

My current logic - Generate a list of files from Remote. Make the file with latest modified time-stamp as my water mark. In the next run copy files with modified time greater than the watermark. Again update watermark.

Problem - The logic fails, when files are copied to remote while preserving the modified time. If a file comes in with modified time lower than the watermark, that file gets skipped.

Any idea how to circumvent the issue?
I dont want to make lists on Remote & Local and find the difference.

Comment: Have you considered `rsync`?

Comment: RSync is the best option for this purpose rather than reinventing the wheel.